# How do I extract a digit from a string with a specific prefix using SQL Regex?

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift

I have a string like this stored in a Redshift table column (event_attribute_value):

```
[{shipment_id:2409777178,sku:1223XLMNPQR,container_scannable_id:blahblah,order_id:3KNCGS6W,quantity_received:3}]
```

I would like to extract '3' from quantity received with a SQL regex.  'quantity_received' can also appear anywhere in the string.

```
select 
  event_attribute_value,
  regexp_substr(event_attribute_value, '/quantity_received:(\d+)/') as quantity 
from receive_events limit 10;
```

This is what I've tried just to get the 'quantity_received:3' out of the string, but it's returning NULL

Comment: Use a `JSON` parser instead.

Comment: What type of regex? JS? PCE? Can you provide the code you've tried and failed?

Comment: I'm trying to extract this from a column in a Redshift table.  I hadn't considered yet that Redshift has a JSON parse function, but it appears to be the case so giving that a shot.

Comment: Can't you query the relevant column instead of the whole table row then?

Comment: Updated question.  JSON parser won't work because it's not valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the regex: `/quantity_received:(\d+)/` and then extract the first capture group. Specify the language for more specific solution.

Comment: Using SQL (parsing from a column in a Redshift table)

Comment: Sorry, I don't have knowledge about working with regexes in SQL. You should tag the question with sql or other relevant tags so someone more knowledgable about that can see the question and help you.

Answer (score 0):

With PHP:

```
$str = '[{shipment_id:2409777178,sku:1223XLMNPQR,container_scannable_id:blahblah,order_id:3KNCGS6W,quantity_received:3}]';
preg_match('/(.*)quantity_received:(\d+)(.*)/', $str, $matches);

echo $matches[2];
```